# How to solve issue : grad_fn = None

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Could anyone advise why `grad_fn = None` for this [pytorch coding](https://github.com/promach/gdas/blob/main/gdas.py#L447) ?

[image: grad_fn = None]

Answer (score 1):

Parameter weights are leaf nodes, *i.e.* those tensor are not the result of an operation, in other words, there is no other tensor node preceding them. You can check using the [`is_leaf`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.is_leaf.html) attribute:

```
>>> nn.Linear(1,1).weight.is_leaf
True
```

The [`grad_fn`](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/autograd_tutorial.html) attribute essentially holds the callback function to backpropagate from a given tensor node. By definition, leaf tensors do not have such function because there is nothing to backpropagate on.